# Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/javac" (-1)

Tags: java, macos, java-8

I have installed java 8  on mac os and when trying to run javac command getting above error.

```
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/javac" (-1)
```

I tried reinstalling using brew cask and by downloading it.
but same error.